# storyboards, InterfaceBuilders, 3.5 Vs 4 inch screen

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am working on a UI that will live on different sizes of iPhone retina ( 3.5 and 4). 
I am using storyboards, now in every viewcontroller I add in Interface builder, I can select the size under simulated metrics, and one option says retina iphone 3.5 screen. which is what I chose.
I then setup constraints for the view controller to maintain top and bottom space to superview. Thinking that with this setup it will work fine on iPhone 3.5, and then resize properly to iphone 4 inch screen.

its not working, do I have to resort to code and do this in viewdidload?

Answer (score 1):

Switching from 3.5" to 4" screens is only made for you to take a look what changes with your layout, how is it resizing. Same goes for Portrait and Lanscape orientations in each viewController.
In order to use autoresizing behavior you have to use [strurs and springs](http://msmvps.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/550x0/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/kevinmcneish/3580.Fig8.002SizeInspector.jpg) on `ios5`.
If your project's deployment target is `ios6` it is recomended to use autolayout.Though it is a little bit more complex and hard to understand, especially using autolayout constraints in code, autolayout saves much time that you would spend to make dynamic things resize properly.

Answer (score 0):

I use this same approach. It works well so lobg as you use autolayout correctly. Play around with the constraints and you'll learn quickly how yo do the layouts efficiently.